# why linking to a static library is generally faster than linking to individual source files?

Tags: linux, unix, static-libraries

case 1. gcc -o program main.o file1.o file2.o

case 2. ar crv foo.a file1.o file2.o
    then, gcc -o program main.o foo.a

At compile time, linking to a static library (case 2) is generally faster than linking to individual source files.(case 1)

Why and what cases?

Any help is appreciated.

```
/* Filename :lib.h */
void file2(char *);
void file1(int);
```

main.c

```
#include "lib.h"
int main()
{
    file1(3);
    file2("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

file1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"
void file1(int arg) {
    printf("you passed %d\n", arg);
}
```

file2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"
void file2(char* arg) {
    printf("you passed %s\n", arg); 
}
```

Comment: What functions in file1.o and file2.o are referenced by functions in main.o?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick  I added source codes

Comment: Please define "faster"

Do you mean run-time execution is faster?  or the building of 'program' is faster?

Comment: Have you actually measured a difference?  Or is this just a supposition?

Comment: @Rich 
In my college exams, it had the following problem.
_If you run gcc -o program main.o file1.o file2.o at once without creating a static library foo.a, the compilation speed may be slower. Explain in some cases._

Comment: I expect that actually finding a situation where this assertion is true will be difficult on modern platforms.  Perhaps on some embedded systems, but most of those are moving to fully featured processors anyway.

Comment: Whoever wrote the exam question appears not to know the difference between compilation and linkage.

Answer (score 0):

The only case I can think of is when your object files are rather large.

Linking against a library will only "pull in" referenced items.  So your executable can be smaller and the functions closer in memory for shorter jumps.  But that is an unlikely thing in a modern platform.